# PyGObject Gtk.Entry Changing progress bar color

Tags: python, gtk, pygobject

I want to change the color of the progress bar of the `Gtk.Entry` widget but am unable to do so by using `Gtk.Widget.override_color()`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In pygtk, you have to override the `GtkStyle` of the widget. In the case of the `GtkProgressBar` the color of the bar is determined by the `bg` attribute's `Gtk.STATE_PRELIGHT` of its style component. [Source](http://www.mail-archive.com/gtk-list@gnome.org/msg13864.html)

So you could do something like:

```
progress_bar.modify_bg(gtk.STATE_PRELIGHT, gtk.gdk.color_parse("blue"))
```

I'm sure something similar can be applied in PyGObject.

Note: You are overriding style settings in Gtk which should be avoided. Styles and themes should be left up to the end user for their own personal tastes.